# Accessing VirtualBOX Machine's server from host OS

Tags: networking

My host machine is a Windows 10 OS.

My Virtual Box guest machine is a Ubuntu OS.

I launch a server and a gateway in my virtual machine in the following addresses:

https://127.0.0.1:8089/

https://127.0.0.1:18443/

I dont have any problem to access them from the guest machine. However, I would like to have access to those addresses from my windows host. How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access services hosted on your virtual machine from your host you need to configure your virtualbox network settings for that machine to bridged network, which will allow it to have an IP inside your LAN. You can find more information on virtualbox network types [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

Another option would be [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) with a NAT network configuration, where your host port would be a port over 1024 and the guest port would be your virtual machine ports (8089 and 18443).